# Can LuaJIT be faster than C?

Tags: c, performance, lua

Is there a scenario where the LuaJIT might be executing code even faster than C?

After searching I found some people talking about the fact that it can at least rival the C-code, but I have never seen/found an example and I cannot inmagine how to create a setting where Lua is faster than C, since Lua seems to rely on C-libraries.

Does anyone have (had) a scenario where this happens and/or can show me an example where Lua is faster than C-Code?

Comment: https://julialang.org/benchmarks/

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for that! Do you have an explanation for the fact that LuaJIT is so much faster than C when it comes to `print_to_file` operations? Since Lua is implemented in C?

Comment: Probably the C version performs unbuffered I/O but I don't know.  I'm sure you can find the source for those benchmarks online.

Comment: on certain case, yes, for example: https://gist.github.com/spion/3049314

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing Lua and LuaJIT. The first one is a pure interpreter and nowhere near 'C performance'.

In LuaJIT on the other hand, while still beeing built with C, the performance critical parts are directly implemented in an assembly language (DynASM, also related to the LuaJIT project). Also, as the name suggests, your Lua code can be JIT compiled if the tracer decices that's the right thing to do.

Here you'll find some (maybe slightly biased) code of how LuaJIT can be extremely fast for table lookups and outperforms C/C++ at least in this case.
https://gist.github.com/spion/3049314

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, it cant be faster (in general).

Both compiled and interpreted languages have their advantages, while interpreted ones are more portable and can be altered during runtime, compiled ones are faster (I am aware that this simplification is not exactly right but its imho good estimate).

JIT is "something in between" and you could get uni course about it, but it has some code interpretation making it *generally slower*. You can get close to "compiled language speed" but never quite 100%.

That being said, its important to compare apples to apples, so equally implemented code, you could absolutely write slower C code that computes the same thing that lua code does.

Answer (score -3):

As documented [here](https://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf), Lua is implmented *in* C. It can only be as fast as C, but is more likely to be slower. It can’t be faster than the language of its own implementation.

Comment: As long as the C code is fully optimized and uses the most appropriate algorithms.   Poorly written C code can certainly be slower than well written LUA code.

Comment: @Brian That's what I thought too, but as the first comment below my post says: There are actually use-cases where LuaJIT was faster than C-Code and my question was how this can happen when it is basically using C-Libraries

Comment: Thanks @JasonGoemaat that makes sense - my thinking was too simplistic. *Can C be faster than C?* Of course, depending on the implementation. Next step then for me would be to see a concrete example. If the `print_to_file` benchmark above is faster with LuaJIT, then lets see the code and not speculate on why. Good learning moment here...

Comment: Iirc from what I've read, luajit can end up being faster under some very specific scenarios. I remember reading that without some specific compiler flags, calling c functions with luajit ffi is faster than in C. It also has runtime information such as hotness of code paths, i think i might have read that makes it faster under some scenarios. Also, a non trivial part of luajit uses raw assembler (The vm, see https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/master/src/vm_x86.dasc https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/master/src/vm_mips.dasc https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/master/src/vm_ppcspe.dasc )

Comment: counterexample: Bootstrapping a compiler. Each stage of the compiler bootstrap processes C code (it's a C compiler in this example), and generates a compiler that runs faster, and generates better code than the one that built it. So C itself can be faster than C. Depends on the compiler.